# how to use nodejs to copy file with spaces and utf8 from remote server

Tags: node.js, shell, escaping

### Problem

I'm trying to build a node app that will compare a local directory with a remote directory, and then copy any new files from the remote directory to the local directory. Unfortunately, many of the files are user generated content, and they contain spaces characters. My current implementation doesn't appear to be escaping the filename strings correctly. **How can I copy these files to my local environment?**

### Current Implementation:

```
// ...
function copyRemoteFile(remoteFile, server, localDir) {
    exec = require('child_process').exec;
    remoteFile = remoteFile.replace(/ /g, '\\\\ ');
    exec('scp ' + server + ':/path/to/files/' + remoteFile + ' ' localDir, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
    });
});
// ...
```

### Current Output

For this input:

```
copyRemoteFile('Screen Shot 2013-12-04 at 1_00_13 PM.png', 'server', '.');
```

I get this output:

> { [Error: Command failed: scp: /path/to/files/Screen: No > such file or directory
>   cp: Shot\: No such file or directory
>   cp: 2013-12-04\: No such file or directory
>   cp: at\: No such file or directory
>   cp: 1_00_13\: No such file or directory
>   cp: PM.png: No such file or directory
>   ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null } '' 'scp: /path/to/files/Screen: No such file or
>   directory\ncp: Shot\: No such file or directory\ncp: 2013-12-04\: No such file or directory\ncp: 
>   at\: No such file or directory\ncp: 1_00_13\: No such file or directory\ncp: PM.png: No such file 
>   or directory\n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install scp

scp.get({
  file: '~/file.txt', // remote file to grab
  user: 'username',   // username to authenticate as on remote system
  host: 'myServer',   // remote host to transfer from, set up in your ~/.ssh/config
  port: '22',         // remote port, optional, defaults to '22'
  path: '~'           // local path to save to (this would result in a ~/file.txt on the local machine)
});
```

Document here: https://github.com/ecto/node-scp

Source code: https://github.com/ecto/node-scp/blob/master/scp.js

---

Space in linux command must be quote:

```
copyRemoteFile('"Screen Shot 2013-12-04 at 1_00_13 PM.png"', 'server', '.');
```

If you call exec linux command via web server, user may use special file name to hack your server, you need to quote parametters

Answer (score 2):

`exec` spawns a shell for you, and forces you to care about escaping.
Try `execFile`:

```
execFile = require('child_process').execFile

execFile('/usr/bin/scp', [server + ':/path/to/files/' + remoteFile, localDir], function...
```

No escaping should be needed.